# Voting to close as duplicate no longer up-votes the auto-generated comment

Tags: bug, comments, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, comment-voting

Until fairly recently, if I voted to close a question as a duplicate, the system would automatically up-vote the existing "*possible duplicate of Foo*" comment (if there was one).

This no longer seems to be happening. Is this a bug or a deliberate change in behaviour?

Comment: @Matt I've never had a userscript doing anything like that. Regarding your other point, *I never inhaled...*

Comment: I was under the impression this existed and have too noted it stop doing this

Comment: I saw just this behavior work fine today. I had voted to close a question as a duplicate today and the already existing comment of *possible duplicate of ...* got a comment upvote on its own. I'm under the impression that this feature has been there and is still working(atleast I could see it in action myself).

Comment: @R.J I tried surfing the close review queue (filtered on duplicates) and couldn't trigger the behaviour on Stack Overflow at least.

Comment: @Duncan - ..And its not working now! :) But the feature was in existence atleast for sometime, because I've seen it in action many a times.

Comment: Is it only in the review queue that you're seeing it break?

Comment: I've only ever seen these auto-upvotes on the comments generated by custom off-topic votes, never on duplicate votes.

Comment: @NickCraver No. I just used that as a source of questions to test with. But I first noticed it in the wild, so to speak. Do I take it from your response that you expect this behaviour to work?

Comment: On [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211272/220332) I generated a possible duplicate link. 4 People have also voted the same way, but it only has 1 upvote

Comment: I manually upvoted a generated "duplicate" comment today after voting to close, and thought "has everyone been manually upvoting these comments lately?"

Comment: @RichardTingle That's my upvote :) I can't vote to close yet here on Meta.