# Where did the hot questions go?

Tags: support, hot-questions

Before the SE topbar was implemented, there was a *hottest-questions-across-the-network* feature I was quite fond of. Where did this feature go? Was it completely wiped out?

I'm sad to see it go.

Comment: It's to the right of "main" pages

Comment: You can see the full list in a standalone page that you can also bookmark: http://stackexchange.com/questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has moved to the [front/main page](https://stackoverflow.com/) on the right side.

[image]